# How to get the size of struct and its contents in bytes in golang?

Tags: memory, go

I have a struct, say:

```
type ASDF struct {
    A   uint64
    B   uint64
    C   uint64
    D   uint64
    E   uint64
    F   string
}
```

I create a slice of that struct: `a := []ASDF{}`

I do operations on that slice of the struct (adding/removing/updating structs that vary in contents); how can I get the total size *in bytes* (for memory) of the slice and its contents? Is there a built-in to do this or do I need to manually run a calculation using `unsafe.Sizeof` and then `len` each string?

Comment: Quick question, isn't struct `ASDF` fixed size since you declare all variable types? Then you can just multiply the size of the struct pointer of `ASDF` by `len(a)`? As you can only append same sized element into slice? Or do I misunderstand how slice work?

Comment: There would be a problem with `string` field though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sum the size of all memory, excluding garbage collector and other overhead. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type ASDF struct {
    A uint64
    B uint64
    C uint64
    D uint64
    E uint64
    F string
}

func (s *ASDF) size() int {
    size := int(unsafe.Sizeof(*s))
    size += len(s.F)
    return size
}

func sizeASDF(s []ASDF) int {
    size := 0
    s = s[:cap(s)]
    size += cap(s) * int(unsafe.Sizeof(s))
    for i := range s {
        size += (&s[i]).size()
    }
    return size
}

func main() {
    a := []ASDF{}

    b := ASDF{}
    b.A = 1
    b.B = 2
    b.C = 3
    b.D = 4
    b.E = 5
    b.F = "ASrtertetetetetetetDF"
    fmt.Println((&b).size())
    a = append(a, b)

    c := ASDF{}
    c.A = 10
    c.B = 20
    c.C = 30
    c.D = 40
    c.E = 50
    c.F = "ASetDF"
    fmt.Println((&c).size())
    a = append(a, c)

    fmt.Println(len(a))
    fmt.Println(cap(a))
    fmt.Println(sizeASDF(a))
}
```

Output:

```
69
54
2
2
147
```

http://play.golang.org/p/5z30vkyuNM

Comment: I don't understand what `cap(s) *` is for? Doesn't it cause wrong result?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid to say that `unsafe.Sizeof` is the way to go here if you want to get any result at all. The in-memory size of a structure is nothing you should rely on. Notice that even the result of `unsafe.Sizeof` is inaccurate: The runtime may add headers to the data that you cannot observe to aid with garbage collection.

For your particular example (finding a cache size) I suggest you to go with a static size that is sensible for many processors. In almost all cases doing such micro-optimizations is not going to pay itself off.

Comment: The [`len(...)`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) function only seems to work with arrays, strings, slices, and channels.  No help with structs =(

Comment: @maerics Just to have a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve, what do you believe this information to be useful for?

Comment: @FUZxxl: no idea, ask OP =)  I'm just commenting from the peanut gallery